# IMPORTRANGE and INDIRECT combination error

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am trying to dynamically import data from another Google sheet (sheet2), to current Google sheet (sheet 1).
In sheet 1, I would like to input the starting cell `A2` and ending cell `D20` in cells `B2` and `B3`, then use `INDIRECT` inside `IMPORTRANGE` to do that:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url", "Training! INDIRECT("B2"):INDIRECT("B3")")
```

but it gave me a *"formula parse error"* message. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You do NOT need `INDIRECT`**

Just use 4 cells as in the image

Cell `C1`: **spreadsheet ID** (1-bdL8Ri4FWWSz1--f2zbg6vMAqnyWDlAyUKVeYc)
Cell `B1`: **tab/sheet name** (Training)
Cell `B2`: **starting cell for range** (J5)
Cell `B3`: **ending cell of range** (K6)

Use the formula: **`=IMPORTRANGE(C1,B1&B2&":"&B3)`**
**OR**  `=IMPORTRANGE(C1,"Training!"&B2&":"&B3)`

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you very much for your help! Really love you, Marikamitsos!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.